# Trouble with SLAM Toolkit

Tags: ros2, slam, rplidar, laser-scan-matcher

I'm looking to convert a ROS1 project setup to ROS2.
In ROS1, I was using a LIDAR, Transforms, Laser Scanner Matcher, and slam_gmapping.

With ROS2, I am still using a LIDAR, Transforms. I had to install the Laser Scanner Matcher from source.   And of course, slam_gmapping isn't the SLAM of choice with ROS2, so I am using the SLAM toolkit.

Currently, I am not getting a /pose or /map from SLAM, but I am seeing this warning:

```
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [WARN] [1709756749.648499254] [slam_toolbox]: Failed to compute odom pose
```

Once the LIDAR is running (and /scan is populated) I set up a transform:

```
run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher --x 0 --y 0 --z 0 --roll 0 --pitch 0 --yaw 0 --frame-id base_link --child-frame-id laser
```

and then launch the laser scanner:

```
ros2 run ros2_laser_scan_matcher laser_scan_matcher \
--ros-args -p use_imu:=false \
--ros-args -p use_odom:=false \
--ros-args -p base_frame:=base_link \
--ros-args -p fixed_frame:=odom \
--ros-args -p publish_tf:=true \
--ros-args -p sigma:=0.1
--ros-args -p max_linear_correction:=0.10 \
--ros-args -p max_angular_correction_deg:=15.0 \
--ros-args -p kf_dist_linear:=0.1 \
--ros-args -p kf_dist_angular:=0.12 \
--ros-args -p max_correspondence_dist:=0.05
```

(I also tried launching it with '--ros-args -p publish_odom:=odom' but there isn't any change)

Then I launch SLAM:

```
ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_sync_launch.py \
odom_frame:=odom \
map_frame:=map \
base_frame:=base_link \
scan_topic:=/scan \
map_update_interval:=1 \
max_laser_rang:=5 \
minimum_travel_distance:=0.1 \
use_scan_matching:=true \
minimum_travel_heading:=1.57 \
do_loop_closing:=true
```

My TFs look like this.
[image]

The zeros are concerning. But I don't know what causes that.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

Using the python launch file was ignoring the parameters.  Running the executable directly with ros2 run, like so, fixed this.

```
ros2 run slam_toolbox sync_slam_toolbox_node \
--ros-args -p odom_frame:=odom \
--ros-args -p base_frame:=base_link \
--ros-args -p map_frame:=map \
--ros-args -p scan_topic:=/scan \
--ros-args -p map_update_interval:=1.0 \
--ros-args -p max_laser_range:=5.0 \
--ros-args -p minimum_travel_distance:=0.1 \
--ros-args -p use_scan_matching:=true \
--ros-args -p minimum_travel_heading:=1.57 \
--ros-args -p do_loop_closing:=true
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not feeding the scan matcher with Odom and IMU data:

```
ros2 run ros2_laser_scan_matcher laser_scan_matcher \
--ros-args -p use_imu:=false \
--ros-args -p use_odom:=false \
```

Shouldn't you switch to use_imu:=True and use_odom:= True ?

Or this package doesn't need other input data, but only scan data to output the pose?

Comment: Those items are not required. With the ROS2 version of the laser scanner matcher the are not even supported.  I've removed those from my command, too.

Comment: Did you try to check if this issue is related to the mapper_params_online_sync.yaml configuration file? When I worked with slam toolbox in ROS2 I have fixed related issues changing values from this file